# Meteor: The application is not spiderable

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

My application is not spiderable both on local and production.

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=`, I can see the following error appears (phantom is killed after 15 seconds):

```
spiderable: phantomjs failed: { [Error: Command failed: ] killed: true, code: null, signal: 'SIGTERM' }
```

It seems that many other people got this problem:

- https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-phantomjs/issues/1
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/Lnm9HFs4MgM/YKDMR80fVecJ
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/7ZbidddRGo4

The thing is I am not using observatory or select2 and all my publications return a cursor. According to me, the problem comes from the minification. I just read [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/7ZbidddRGo4) that someone succeed to display "SyntaxError: Parse error". How can I know more about what is going wrong with Phantom and which file is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was coming from SSL. [You can have a complete overview of what I did here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/dPLss2idrJg)

Edit the spiderable source and add `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` to the phantomjs command line, it will work.

Comment: This solution has been helpfully packaged here: https://github.com/Gentlenode/spiderable-ssl. It worked perfectly for me. (FYI, I also used https://github.com/dfischer/meteor-phantomjs to load phantomjs on the server)

Answer (score 3):

This happens when spiderable is waiting for subscriptions that fail to return any data and end up timing out, as mentioned in some of the threads you linked.

Make sure that all of your [publish functions](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) are either returning a cursor, a (possibly empty) list of cursors, or sending `this.ready()`.

[Meteor APM](https://meteorapm.com/) may be useful in determining which publications aren't returning.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know more about what is wrong with phatomjs, you might try this [code](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable) (1):

```
// Put your URL below, no "?_escaped_fragment_=" necessary
var url = "http://your-url.com/";
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url);
setInterval(function() {
  var ready = page.evaluate(function () {
    if (typeof Meteor !== 'undefined'
        && typeof(Meteor.status) !== 'undefined'
        && Meteor.status().connected) {
      Deps.flush();
      return DDP._allSubscriptionsReady();
    }
    return false;
  });
  if (ready) {
    var out = page.content;
    out = out.replace(/<script[^>]+>(.|\n|\r)*?<\/script\s*>/ig, '');
    out = out.replace('<meta name=\"fragment\" content=\"!\">', '');
    console.log(out);
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 100);
```

For use in local, install [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). Then outside your app, create a file `phantomtest.js` with the code above. And run `phantomjs phantomtest.js`

Another thing that maybe you can try is to use UglifyJS to catch some errors in the minified JS file as [Payner35 did](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-phantomjs/issues/1#issuecomment-36165339).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but nothing appears in my terminal. It seems that ready is undefined.